Can't install Mariadb on Ubuntu 24.04
I am trying to install NextCloud on a Ubuntu 24.04 server.
right from the start I get error when trying to install Mariadb.
*$ sudo apt-get install  mariadb-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  mailx mariadb-test
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mariadb-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,381 kB of archives.
After this operation, 55.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 84958 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-server_1%3a10.11.8-0ubuntu0.24.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mariadb, action "stop" failed.
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
Attempt to stop MariaDB/MySQL server returned exitcode 5
There is a MariaDB/MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server_1%3a10.11.8-0ubuntu0.24.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new mariadb-server package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server_1%3a10.11.8-0ubuntu0.24.04.1_amd64.deb
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)*

I did not install MYsql db.
~$ sudo systemctl stop mysql
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
*Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-plugin-provider-bzip2 : Depends: mariadb-server (>= 1:10.11.1-1) but it is not installed
 mariadb-plugin-provider-lz4 : Depends: mariadb-server (>= 1:10.11.1-1) but it is not installed
 mariadb-plugin-provider-lzma : Depends: mariadb-server (>= 1:10.11.1-1) but it is not installed
 mariadb-plugin-provider-lzo : Depends: mariadb-server (>= 1:10.11.1-1) but it is not installed
 mariadb-plugin-provider-snappy : Depends: mariadb-server (>= 1:10.11.1-1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).*

How can I solve this issue?
Thnx in advance.

Try: sudo apt --fix-broken install
